# Getting 'line 9: 803: command not found' for for loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, terminal

Hi i'm using this for loop and am having issues with the 803 command not being found:

```
#!/bin/bash


declare -i file=803
for ((i=1;i<12;i++))


do
    $file += i


        /home/georgesmith/software/STAR-2.7.9a/source/STAR --genomeDir /home/georgesmith/B2_Assignment --readFilesCommand gunzip -c --readFilesIn /home/georgesmith/B2_Assignment/contrast_7/SRR$

        /home/georgesmith/software/STAR-2.7.9a/source/STAR --genomeDir /home/georgesmith/B2_Assignment --readFilesCommand gunzip -c --readFilesIn /home/georgesmith/B2_Assignment/contrast_7/SRR$



done
```

any help would be great!

Comment: Please format your code in a readable way, one statement per line. `declare -i file=803 for ((i=1;i<12;i++))` is not a valid statement.

Comment: Try changing the code: ``$file += i`` -> ``let "file += i"``. The line can also be deleted, but I assume that you plan to use the sequence: 804, 806, 809, 813, 818, 824, 831, 839, 848, 858, 869.

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out the problems here.

Comment: `$file += i` is not valid bash syntax. `file=$((file+i))` should work instead. You don't actually use that variable, however, what is it supposed to do?